# Acronyms are abbreviated in the first use

Tags: acro

I use acro package for acronyms and `\ac{id}` through my text. However, it does not show the acronym explicitly in the first use, it is always abbreviated.

I am using TeXstudio 2.10.8 on linux 16.04.

How can I solve it?

Edit: My piece of code: (I put all the included libraries in case you see some incompatibilities)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry} % decreases margins
\usepackage{cite} % takes care of citations
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{xcolor} %better colors

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %National characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}

\acsetup{first-style=short}

\DeclareAcronym{test}{
    short = TEST ,
    long  = Example Abbreviation for Test ,
    class = abbrev
}

    \title{\textbf{A Title}}
    \author{Submitted by: Me}
    \date{\today}


\begin{document}

    \maketitle  

    \begin{abstract}
        Some text related to my abbreviation \ac{test}.
    \end{abstract}

\clearpage
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=Abbreviations]

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}


\end{document}
```

And the output shows that abbreviation library works as it should be:

[image: And the output shows that abbreviation library works as it should be:]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: You probably have a setting somewhere that causes this behavior. Please provide an MWE and we can look at the issue in detail.

Comment: oh, thank you. Sorry for being that noob. I am quiet new in this forum...

Comment: I don't use `acro` but doesn't `\acsetup{first-style=short}` make the first use only show the short form?

Comment: gosh, seriously!? You are right. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments